# how to build Elasticsearch source code using gradle?

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle

I download elasticsearch source code from :https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch,

I found there is a `build.gradle`file,and I have install gradle,
how to build source it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simply run gradle?

Comment: In fact,I need Elasticsearch reference with HTML format.How to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a description fo the way you can build it in the readme file in the repo. According to it:

> **Building from Source**
>
> Elasticsearch uses Gradle for its build system. You’ll need to have
>   version 2.13 of Gradle installed.
>
> In order to create a distribution, simply run the `gradle assemble`
>   command in the cloned directory.
>
> The distribution for each project will be created under the
>   `build/distributions` directory in that project.
>
> See the TESTING file for more information about running the
>   Elasticsearch test suite.

So all you need is to get into the root directory and in command line call `gradle assemble`, if you have Gradle installed properly, you will find all artifacts under `build/distributions` directory

Answer (score 1):

`gradle assemble` seems to yield some errors such as `cannot find symbol` in my macOS environment.

According to the latest description in the repo (as of time writing the answer):

To build a distribution for your local OS and print its output location upon completion, run:

```
./gradlew localDistro
```

To build a distribution for another platform, run the related command:

```
./gradlew :distribution:archives:linux-tar:assemble
./gradlew :distribution:archives:darwin-tar:assemble
./gradlew :distribution:archives:windows-zip:assemble
```

To build distributions for all supported platforms, run:

```
./gradlew assemble
```

Distributions are output to distributions/archives.